# Linq with update query

Tags: c#, linq

How to write query like this for linq?
I'm beginning learn to linq recently and still can't understand.

```
string update = @"UPDATE Users SET Score = Score + @score,
                               Bonus = Bonus + @bonus
                         WHERE Username = @username";
cmd = new SqlCommand(update, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", txtScore.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bonus", txtBonus.Text);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
XtraMessageBox.Show("Updated!");
con.Close();
```

I dont' know why there is no "Set" clause in linq...
btw, I'm using entity framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq (and Entity Framework) doesn't have a way to modify objects in a collection. You need to gather the objects to modify, modify them, then trigger EF to save the data back to the database.

```
// get the objects you want to modify
var users = context.Users.Where(x => x.Username == myUsername);

foreach (var user in users)
{
    // change the properties
    user.Bonus += bonusToAdd;
    user.Score += scoreToAdd;
}

// EF will pick up those changes and save back to the database.
context.SaveChanges();
```

---

Of course, `Username` is most likely a primary key, so you shouldn't have more than one `User` record with that name. Simply replace the query and foreach with:

```
var user = context.Users.Single(x => x.Username == myUsername);
user.Bonus += bonusToAdd;
user.Score += scoreToAdd;
```

You can use `SingleOrDefault` to help out with exceptions if you attempt to lookup a user which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

the update keyword isn't used in Linq. You can perform updates as follows:

```
var users = (from p in Context.Users
             where p.Username == username
             select p).ToList().ForEach(x =>
             {
                 x.Score += score;
                 x.Bonus += bonus;
             });
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Or, if you'd prefer not to use lambda expressions, this would work the same:

```
var users = (from p in Context.Users
             where p.Username == username
             select p).SingleOrDefault();

foreach (var user in users)
{
    user.Score += score;
    user.Bonus += bonus;
}           

Context.SaveChanges();
```